# MYSQL to auto increment a 16 digit number for each entry

Tags: mysql

I am wanting MYSQL to assign a 16 digit number for each entry as it will be used for a private credit card service. How do I do this??

I had set the field which is called id to auto-increment and bigint but it still only assigns the numbers in order starting with 1.

I am needing the numbers to be 16 digits long and random.

Please help!

Comment: Normally, one or more digits of a credit card number contain a check value of some kind to catch typing errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the auto increment number to start at any number

```
ALTER TABLE MY_TABLE AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000000000000000; -- the first 16-digit number
```

The only restriction on the number specified is that it be not less than the current maximum number for the auto increment column for the specified table.

This however will not provide *random* numbers.

To create a random 16 digit number, you could use a trigger on insert that uses `PASSWORD()` function, which creates a 16-digit hexadecimal number, and convert it to a number if you need by calling `UNHEX()` and `SUBSTR()` on the result to capture 16 random digits.

For security, you should pass a seed with a value, eg the new id value concatenated with another piece of info from the record concatenated with a constant concatenated with perhaps the current time. It's up to you how far you want to go.

The random number could be done in your application code too, whcih may be a better option as it's easier to debug and control than database kung fu.

Comment: So with this we would receive for the first number: 1000000000000000 and then the second number: 1000000000000001 ?

Comment: Would your edit for the random number be initiated in PHP or where?

Comment: You could easily do it within the database as a trigger, but if yo're more comfortable with PHP, and especially if the PHP app is the only code adding rows, do it in PHP. Database triggers are to be used with caution, as they are hard to debug if there's a problem